# How to maintaine a local git fork from a repo with many branches

Tags: git, scm

I'm using a public git repository and adjusting it to my specific needs, meaning that the changes are not worthy of being merged upstream.

Repo is in github (`upstream`), and we maintain our own git server (`origin`), where the fork will be store.

The original repo is quite active and has 10+ release branches plus as many tags. I'd be having my own  branches, which will build up upon those releases

I guess I'll have to regularly merge the changes from `upstream` onto my own branches and then push this to my `origin`. 
Now question(s):

- Is there a way to store the `upstream` into the repository itself? I mean, I'd like to clone the project from `origin` and have the configuration for `upstream` already there.
- What's the best way to go about having my branches up to date with `upstream`: pull and merge them locally and the push to `origin`, or is 
  there a better or more standard way to do this?

Comment: Any comment on the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation with a repository I maintain.  It's a fork of Linq2Db, and it's for a legacy version of SQL CE that my team are stuck on, but I don't think would be useful for anyone other than us.

The way I approached it was by having a branch in my repository called `upstream-master`, that gets updated from the `upstream/master` branch.  I can then merge it into my master branch as you would normally.

How you'd handle releases really depends on the branching strategy that the project you're forking works on.  I always tag releases, but don't make release branches, unless I need to make modifications to an existing release, which is rare.  More information would be helpful for us to suggest something appropriate to your situation.

The one other thing I'd note, if you're releasing your fork as a nuget package, even if it's only internally, make sure you change the package ID accordingly, so you don't clash with the official version.  You don't want your CI server accidentally installing the vanilla version instead of your fork, this could cause weird problems, and quite a bit of head-scratching.  Ask me how I know! ;-)